# Form is not responding to submit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have form, user must fill it and submit but I have no reaction from this form

First I thought there is a problem with action directive of the form, so used redirect method in the views but no help

```py
def organization_info(request):
    organization_form = OrganizationInformationForm()

    context = {
        'organization_form': organization_form
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST")
        organization_form = OrganizationInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if organization_form.is_valid():
            print("VALID")
            new_org = OrganizationInformation.objects.create(**organization_form.cleaned_data)
            print("FILLED")

            return redirect(organization_list)

    return render(request, 'organization_form.html', context)
```

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Organization Name:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ organization_form.name }}
            </div>
        .
        .
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I only have the "POST" printed on the log no any errors

Comment: Can you use your browser's dev tools to watch the requests that are being sent?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browsers' console?

Comment: What errors are you expecting? You don't seem to be using `organization_form` in the template, so I don't know how it could be displaying errors.

Comment: I used `organization_form` just omitted to shorten the html code

Comment: The console is showing post method but it's not redirecting to page it should and not registereing

Answer (score 0):

add form handler path in action and try again

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action={'your form handler path'}>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Organization Name:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary because I used redirect() in form handler function.

Comment: Your new object should anyway be created because the redirect is after the create method

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action attribute to your form.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" **action="url-of-handler"**>

</form>
```

More on this topic: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: I think no, because in my views.py i used redirect() I dont think it's necessary to use action attribute